# Copy data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked through this website and got a code similar to this. 
My problem is that the code is opening the files but not pasting the data.
The workbook where I am trying to paste the data is TRY 5.xlsm and the range where I am pasting is B3. I am copying the data from workbook Copy of BAFD.xlsx and the range is `V1:AF1`.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Copy of BAFD.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Practise\TRY 5.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_30Nov")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Calib29_30")

    With ws1.Range("V1:AF1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to select anything or use that With statement - does this work?

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Copy of BAFD.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Practise\TRY 5.xlsm")

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_30Nov")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Calib29_30")

ws1.Range("V1:AF1", ws1.Range("V1:AF1").End(xlDown)).Copy
ws2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

---

EDIT: OK let's take a different approach, we'll define 2 range objects and transfer the values programatically rather than using Copy / Paste:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Copy of BAFD.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Practise\TRY 5.xlsm")

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_30Nov")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Calib29_30")

Set rngCopy = ws1.Range("V1:AF1", ws1.Range("V1:AF1").End(xlDown))
Set rngPaste = ws2.Range("B3").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
rngPaste.Value = rngCopy.Value

End Sub
```

---

EDIT - This should now work through the sheets and copy the data across for each one:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
Dim strWs1 As String, strWs2 As String, i As Integer, arrSheets() As String
Dim blnExists1 As Boolean, blnExists2 As Boolean

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Copy of BAFD.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\43707844\Desktop\Change of weights\Svar\BAFD\Practise\TRY 5.xlsm")

'Put all BAFD.xlsx worksheet names into a string array so we can check that they exist
ReDim arrSheets(wb1.Worksheets.Count)
For i = 1 To wb1.Worksheets.Count
    arrSheets(i) = wb1.Worksheets(i).Name
Next

'Loop through all sheets in TRY 5, identify numbers and transfer data across
For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
    Debug.Print "WS2 Name: " & ws2.Name
    strWs1 = Mid(ws2.Name, 5, 2)
    strWs2 = Mid(ws2.Name, 8, 2)
    Debug.Print "WS2 1 Number: " & strWs1
    Debug.Print "WS2 2 Number: " & strWs2
    blnExists1 = False
    blnExists2 = False
    'Check that sheets exist in BAFD.xlsx
    For i = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        If arrSheets(i) = "Calib_" & strWs1 Then blnExists1 = True
        If arrSheets(i) = "Calib_" & strWs2 Then blnExists2 = True
    Next

    Debug.Print "WS1 Exists: " & blnExists1
    Debug.Print "WS2 Exists: " & blnExists2

    'If both exist, copy the values across. If they don't, move on to the next one
    If blnExists1 = True And blnExists2 = True Then
        'Get first sheet details
        Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_" & strWs1)
        Set rngCopy = ws1.Range("V1:AF1", ws1.Range("V1:AF1").End(xlDown))
        Set rngPaste = ws2.Range("B3").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
        rngPaste.Value = rngCopy.Value
        'Get second sheet details
        Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_" & strWs2)
        Set rngCopy = ws1.Range("V1:AF1", ws1.Range("V1:AF1").End(xlDown))
        Set rngPaste = ws2.Range("N3").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
        rngPaste.Value = rngCopy.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Made the above changes but it still doesn't work. Sheet TRY 5 remains empty.

Comment: I tried the code in a new workbook but it still doesnot work.

Comment: Edited - try that. If it doesn't work, use F8 to step through it and follow progress on the sheets... we could try using `ws2.Range("B3").Value = "HELLO"` to prove that it is selecting the correct worksheet.

Comment: I have one more doubt. The workbook BAFD.xlsx has 20 more worksheets namely Calib_29 Nov, Calib_28 Nov and so on. The workbook TRY 5 has 20 sheets namely Calib29_30, Calib 29_28, etc. The next step is to copy data from sheet Calib_28Nov to sheet Calib 29_28 then from sheet Calib_27Nov to sheet Calib 28_27 and so on. How do i follow the same procedure for all the sheets without copying the above code again and again.

Comment: Hi Anuz - you will need to loop through the worksheets using `Dim shtTemp as Worksheet` then `For Each shtTemp in wb1.Workbooks`. I can help more if you give more examples of sheet names. What happens when Calib_01 Dec arrives? Which sheet should that be copied to in TRY 5? There's no month reference in the sheet name. Will it always need to be pasted via this relationship Calib_XX to Calib_YY_XX (using the XX to identify the sheet) ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The workbook **Copy of BAFD.xlsx** has sheets namely:- Calib_30Nov,Calib_29Nov,Calib_28Nov,Calib_27Nov,Calib_26Nov till Calib_10Nov. Workbook TRY 5.xlsm has sheets namely:- Calib 30_29, Calib 29_28, Calib 28_27, Calib 27_26 till Calib 11_10. There is no Calib_01Dec. I have to compare the data for the month of november.Here i need to compare the data of 2 consecutive dates. So on the sheet Calib 30_29 i am pasting the data of sheet Calib_30Nov and Calib_29Nov and then comparing the data as per these two dates.

Comment: On the sheet Calib 29_28 i am pasting the data of sheets Calib_29Nov and Calib_28Nov and comparing there values.I need to do the same for the rest.

Comment: Ok - on the compare sheets, where are you pasting the values? I know B3 is where the data from the first date is pasted from, where does the data from second date need go to?

Comment: The data from the second date goes to N3. The compare sheet is TRY 5. Once i paste all the data i compare the data on the same sheet.

Comment: OK I've edited it again - try that and let me know if there are any errors (not tested on my side)

Comment: Its not pasting the values. Its opening the files but not copying and pasting it.

Comment: Can you put a break point on `Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Calib_" & strWs1)` and see if it reaches that bit? Then step through it using F8 and make sure that each line is working as expected.

Comment: i added breakpoint. Executed the program without the loop part. It works fine if i remove the loop but with the loop it doesnt paste the values.                                                        I added a msgbox **MsgBox (strWs1)** after **strWs1 = Mid(ws2.Name, 5, 2)** and **MsgBox (strWs2)** after **strWs2 = Mid(ws2.Name, 8, 2)** And when i run the program i get **msgbox with b** and when i click ok then i get a **msgbox with 0_** then i click ok and i get **b** then **9_** then **b** then **8_** then **b** then **7_** and when i click ok the program remains still without any changes

Comment: Looks like I miscounted the characters; the strWS variables are meant to return the numbers - change these : `strWs1 = Mid(ws2.Name, 7, 2)` and `strWs2 = Mid(ws2.Name, 10, 2)`

Comment: It still doesnt work. Is there any way to attach a sample of those excel sheets so that you can see the exact problem.